# Oracle Reports: How to Get Image - that I Inserted It - Under A Repeating Frame?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, report, oraclereports

I inserted an image(B_3) to my report. How can I get this image under repeating frame (R_1)?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- image should be a little bit *smaller* than the frame
- paint the frame white or yellow or some similar color (so that it is clearly visible on the screen)
- make the frame surround the image, i.e. the image should - visibly - be placed "inside" the frame
- select the frame in Paper Layout editor (click on it)
- go to the **Layout** menu and use:

  - send to back if this frame should be the "last" - this is usually used for the outmost frame, or
  - move backward - you might need to repeat this action several times, depending on how many "steps" (*layers*) separate image and frame
- you're done once you see the image "above" the frame
- remove frame fill color

Comment: After I paint frame, image doesn't seem. And when I go to Layout menu, "send to back", "bring to front" etc. all of items are disable.

Comment: After you paint the frame, it is located "above" the image so you can't see it. That's why you have to "move it backward" until it is placed "below" the image. That's how I do it and - it works, if properly performed.